# Why does this loop run infinite times? Comma separated conditions in for loop

Tags: c

Program code :

```
int main() 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < 0, 5; i++) 
        printf("%d ", i); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The loop above is executed infinite times.

What does `i<0,5` mean, and how it is evaluated?

Comment: Subexpression `i < 0` will never be the result of expression `(i < 0), 5`. The result of expression `(i < 0), 5` will always be exactly 5, and never anything that is not 5. Value of 5 is considered as `true` so the `for` loop runs forever, because the condition will be `true` forever.

Comment: As illustrated by OPs comments on the answer by Paul Evans, explaining the comma operator is not sufficient to answer this question. It is hence not a duplicate as proposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on operator precedence, this is interpreted as `(i < 0), 5`. The comma operator evaluates all statements, but discards their values except the last. So for practical purposes the loop reads as

`for (int i = 0; 5; ++i) {...}`

Because a non-zero value is interpreted as `true` in C/C++, this is equivalent to:

`for (int i = 0; true; ++i) {...}`

which is an infinite loop.

Comment: Nice explanation, bridging the gap between "How does comma operator work?" and "Why is this infinite?".

Answer (score 2):

> why `i<0,5` how it is evaluated?

Because the value of a comma expression is its last value. The values in this comma expression are`i < 0` and `5`. This first is evaluated to `false` and thrown away! The second (and last) is `5` which is `true`. That is used as the `for` loop condition expression.

A `for` loop runs until its condition expression is `false`, so this loop run forever.

Comment: then why it runs infine time

Comment: @avanish Added that to answer.

Comment: @ Paul Evans but value of i is also increasing so when value of i=5 then it should stop

Comment: @avanish Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to check yourself. Try:

```
int main() 
{ 
    int i, y; 
    for (i = 0; i < 0, 5; i++) 
    {
        y = (i < 0, 5);
        printf("%d ", y); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And you know that second expression in your list is the value of the comma expression.

Answer (score 0):

In the condition of the loop there is used the comma operator

```
for (i = 0; i < 0, 5; i++) 
    printf("%d ", i);
```

From the C Standard (6.5.17 Comma operator)

> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
>   expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that
>   of the right operand. **Then the right operand is evaluated; the result
>   has its type and value**

So this expression with the comma operator

```
i < 0, 5
```

has two operands and can be rewritten for clarity like

```
( i < 0 ), ( 5 )
```

So the value of the expression according to the quote from the C Standard is the value of the second operand that is `5`.

As 5 is not equal to 0 then the condition always evaluates to logical true and you have an infinite loop.

From the C Standard (6.8.5 Iteration statements)

> 4 **An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to
>   be executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal
>   to 0**. The repetition occurs regardless of whether the loop body is
>   entered from the iteration statement or by a jump.155